# Configure GOROOT in Goland when using docker

Tags: docker, go, goland

I am building a Go project with Docker in the new GoLand IDE. Unfortunately, I am not able to cofigure my `GOROOT` correctly, making it not possible to use the GoLand futures to the max.

I have the following dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.9.3

# allows app_env to be set during build (defaults to empty string)
ARG app_env
# sets an environment variable to app_env argument, this way the variable will persist in the container for use in code
ENV APP_ENV $app_env


COPY ./ /go/src/github.com/Name/ProjectName/

WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/Name/ProjectName/app

# install all dependencies
RUN go get ./...

# build the binary
RUN go build

# Put back once we have an application
RUN app

EXPOSE 8080
```

I now execute my project as follows:

1. `docker build -t project-name .`
2. `docker run -it -v ~/project-dir:/go/src/github.com/Name/ProjectName/app`

This works, however, I cannot find how I can configure GoLand to use the path on my Docker image `usr/local/go/bin` for my GoRoot, is that even possible in GoLand? (If not, why even bother adding 'docker support'?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2018.1.2, it's impossible to use GoLand to develop Go applications that have their source code inside containers. The source code of your application, its dependencies, and Go itself need to be installed on your machine.

If anyone has any idea on how to improve the Docker based development support, suggestions are welcomed, see: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-3322

As for why even bother adding support for Docker in the IDE? You can launch containers, you can use docker compose, and a host of other tools from the IDE. However, with the way containers work, there is no way for the IDE to get the source from the container and infer them.

Furthermore, your container should not include the Go sources/workspace in the final container, so that it's optimized for size and deployment speed. You can use something like this to run, but be aware that additional work may be required.

```
FROM golang:1.9.3 as build-env

# allows app_env to be set during build (defaults to empty string)
ARG app_env
# sets an environment variable to app_env argument, this way the variable     will persist in the container for use in code
ENV APP_ENV $app_env

COPY ./ /go/src/github.com/Name/ProjectName/

WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/Name/ProjectName/app

# install all dependencies
RUN go get ./...

# build the binary
RUN go build -o /my_app

# final stage
FROM scratch

COPY --from=build-env /my_app /

# Put back once we have an application
CMD ["/my_app"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just wondering: why did jetbrains choose to not make this possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's really not something we can fix. There's no way for us to access the files inside containers without doing something like an SSH bridge, or similar. And that's not exactly a good development experience nor it allows for using minimal docker containers.

Comment: @dlsniper There is awesome support for building inside a Docker container in PyCharm. Could you provide something along this lines? I assume in PyCharm it works with mounting the src directories.

Comment: We are still exploring how to use Docker containers for development, see the ticket in my response. Personally, I don't understand why would anyone do actual development inside a Docker container, using git, various go tools, and doing commits from there. It goes against everything containers are supposed to be and it's using them as Virtual Machines rather than containers. That being said, my opinion doesn't matter in this case, and when we'll figure out how to support this case, we'll update the ticket. I hope this helps.

Comment: This does not make sense. PHPStorm (another Jet Brains app) has an option to load PHP from a running docker container. It loads PHP from the container so you do not need PHP installed on your host machine. Then PHPStorm looks/infers to all the PHP lib in the running container. I'm not sure how, maybe it maps a docker volume. GoLand could try what PHP Storms does.